# Password asked when I access a network drive

Tags: windows-7, networking, passwords

I can't access network drive. It always asked the password although I have deactivated the password.

I've already restart my PC, but it still, I can't access it.
What's wrong?

Normal network. I access `\\computername\` and it asks for password. The computer used to have password but not anymore. This morning it works and now it doesn't.

The other computer that have accessed it once can access it.

Comment: Where is the network drive located at ? What operating systems are involved? What kind of network ? A small workgroup, a windows domain? Beeing asked for credentials when trying to access ressources of a remote machine is perfectly normal in most cases. Give some more information.

Comment: I use Windows 7, a small workgroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that both PCs use Windows 7.

You  have to deactivate password protected sharing, like it is described [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/185429-password-protected-sharing-turn-off-windows-7-a.html),
and you have to make sure that you have the exact same users with the exact same passwords on both machines.